# Creating simple select on many-to-many relation

Tags: mysql, postgresql, rdbms

Lets say I have this tables:

```
country:
country_id,
country_name;

currency:
currency_id,
currency_name;

country_currency:
country_id,
currency_id;
```

I would like to select and show all countries having two or more currencies. How should my query look like?

Comment: Try something. Still struggling? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Join all the tables with the common columns, then group the result by country_id, and count the number of rows (or currency) per group as shown below.

```
SELECT A.COUNTRY_ID, COUNT(*) NUMBER_OF_CURRENCY 
FROM COUNTRY A 
    INNER JOIN COUNTRY_CURRENCY B ON A.COUNTRY_ID = B.COUNTRY_ID 
    INNER JOIN CURRENCY C ON B.CURRENCY_ID=C.CURRENCY_ID
GROUP BY A.COUNTRY_ID 
HAVING NUMBER_OF_CURRENCY > 1 ;
```

A better query would be:

```
SELECT COUNTRY_NAME 
FROM COUNTRY 
WHERE COUNTRY_ID IN (
                    SELECT COUNTRY_ID 
                    FROM COUNTRY_CURRENCY 
                    GROUP BY COUNTRY_ID 
                    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
                     );
```

Comment: ... Or just >1 . Although there’s a lot more query here than is strictly necessary

Comment: @Strawberry I guess the second query is what is necessary.

Comment: Nope. The solution can be simpler, but the op wants to show countries, not country ids

Comment: Ok I will be glad to see your answer.

Comment: We’ll just have to see how successfully the op responds to my earlier comment